# How can I use Integer Auto Increment Field in DBx4 with BlackFish?

Tags: delphi, auto-increment, dbexpress, blackfish

I am trying to use auto incremental fields in dbx4 with a black fish database
I have a simple table Structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE tblTABname (
    ID int AUTOINCREMENT Primary Key,
    Description varchar(100) NOT NULL );
```

Before Open I am doing the :

```
qryTAB.FieldByName( ‘ID’).AutoGenerateValue := arAutoInc;
cdsTAB.FieldByName( ‘ID’).AutoGenerateValue := arAutoInc;
```

After Open:

```
qryTab.FieldByName('ID').ProviderFlags := [pfInWhere, pfInKey];
cdsTab.FieldByName('ID').ProviderFlags := [pfInWhere, pfInKey];
```

If I do:

```
cdsTAB.Edit;
cdsTAB.FieldByName(‘Description’).value := ‘Test’;
cdsTAB.Post;
```

Or if I use this in a DBGRID, it fails with the error :

> “Field ‘ID’ must have a value”

Witch should have been generated .

If I run an INSERT Query it works fine, with or without the “AutoGenerateValue := arAutoInc” lines.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling CDSTab.EDIT, call CDSTab.INSERT to add a new row, only call CDSTab.EDIT when your cursor is on a record already, and to edit the value of that record.